# I am getting this error in my node application :Error: Cannot find module 'delayed-stream'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I suddenly started seeing this error in my `node.js` application. I am using `Typescript, MYSQL, Sequelize and Express.js`. I have googled and found nothing that helped me.
How can I fix this error?

```
Error: Cannot find module 'delayed-stream'
```

It throws this error when I try to start the `node.js` app.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to run `npm install delayed-stream` ? This should solve your problem